# Does Twilio Flex UI support Node 18 and NPM 8?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex, twilio-cli

I am trying to follow the instructions from Twilio Flex found at: [Twilio Flex Quickstart: Getting Started with React Plugin Development](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin)

I keep running into errors and can not figure them out. I've tried doing this on Windows and macOS and it's the same result. I am using NVM to use Node.js v18.13.0 and NPM v8.19.3. The only thing I can think of is that maybe Twilio Flex does not support the current versions of Node and NPM. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Terminal output:

```
Starting development server (static)...
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3100//
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from undefined
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/username/plugin-sample
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.twilio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Here is the commands I have run so far (in order):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
nvm install --lts
brew tap twilio/brew && brew install twilio
twilio login
twilio flex:plugins:create plugin-sample --install --flexui2
cd plugin-sample
twilio flex:plugins:start
```

I have tried installing legacy versions of Node 16 and Node 14 with varying degrees of success. At one point I was able to actually have the plugin running on localhost but I had many errors and it would not let me publish the plugin. Since then, I have not been able to recreate this somewhat successful output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [installation instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins/cli/install#prerequisites), Node 10.12 through 14 are supported. They are working towards support for 16. So using node 18 would be a very likely cause of the error.

You can switch to a supported version by doing `nvm install 14`.

To keep this version as your new default, you'll need to set it: `nvm alias default 14`.

Comment: Thank you Brian! Should I use Flex UI 2.x or 1.x?

Comment: Unless there is some limiting factor specific to you, I would use 2.X since it's the most recent and is now out of beta